# How to get a list of Java classes which are called at the time of running hadoop hdfs command?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Is there any command by which we can find what are all the java classes that would be called if we submit a command like:

`hdfs dfs –copyFromLocal data.txt /tmp`

Comment: Are you asking what code gets run when you execute that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As such there is no command to get Class diagram of internally called classes. But below is one sequence of classes invoked when any of the `hadoop shell` command is run on terminal.

First class is `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.java`

If you type `hadoop fs` or `hdfs dfs` without any option, `printUsage` method of `FsShell.java` is called to display help.

On terminal you will get output of printUsage method like this.
[image: hadoop fs without arg output]

Second class is `org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand`,  is called from within FsShell class.

all the shell commands like (-ls)Ls.class, (-mkdir)Mkdir.class are registered with the help of `CommandFactory.java` in `FsShell` class.

Eventually you have a list of hadoop commands classes like below.

Few of them have some static inner classes in it for similar kind of functionality.

```
(-ls,-lsr)org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Ls.java
(-mkdir)org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Mkdir.java
(-mv) org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.MoveCommands.java
(-rm,rmdir,-rmr,-expunge)org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Delete.java
```

And the celebrities of town, because everybody knows them i.e.copy commands.

```
(-getmerge,-cp,-copyFromLocal,copyToLocal,-get,-put)org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CopyCommands.java
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you think this answer has solved or answered your question properly. Please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? for more information